# Is storing an entire map in Guice using a single binding considered bad practice?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

I need to store a `Map<Integer, User>` in order to lookup users by ID. Before using Guice, I would have created a `UserManager` which composites the map within itself and has 2 functions to get and set users.

To avoid the need of a separate (possibly poltergeist) wrapper class, is it considered bad practice to create a class such as `UserMap extends HashMap<Integer, User>` and bind this to a singleton instance instead? I can then just inject the `UserMap` itself without anything else to worry about. This may violate composition over inheritance... but considering its only purpose is to act as a map?

Is there any other suitable ways to store `Map` (and other) types for global access without static variables (i.e. without a static non-Guice `UserManager.get(23)`)?

I feel like the dozens of "manager" classes I am creating are not useful and simply provide a wrapper to pre-existing functions.

Answer (score 2):

I would say that extending `HashMap` instead of doing your own interface would go against best practices.

Here are a few reasons

- If you later wanted to fetch the user by id from a database you would need to rewrite all code that touches this `Map`
- Makes testing easier
- Gives an easy overview what operations are permitted

It's better to have a clear interface that defines the responsibilities of the UserManager which might grow more complex as your app progresses.

Comment: That's a very good point. I feel as if it would go against best practices to have single-line functions that just `return userMap.get(param);` too though - thus my dilemma.

Comment: @ThomasRyder not sure why you feel that. That you store it in a `HashMap` is an implementation detail that the users of the interface / class need not to worry about.

Comment: @ThomasRyder map is very generic and that should be a reason good enough that you want it to be encapsulated in any DI context. What if you need another map with the same generics? You'll annotate, ok, but that will be much less readable. Also with Java 8, most managers methods are now reduced to a a long chain of stream calls making them technically 1 line long. Just go with the wrapper, you won't get any bad surprises.

Comment: @ThomasRyder if you feel the answer is satisfactory feel free to accept it